# External css rule applied to parent window via jQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two windows. The parent window A and the child window B. When i close the child window B i want to apply this external css rule to my parent window B via jQuery or javascript:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
                "pagingType": "full_numbers"
            } );
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I had two other rules worked using javascript. But i don't use how to use javascript for the above rule.

Below is the rules that work:

```
opener.document.getElementById("tableContainer").innerHTML = result;
            opener.document.getElementById("tableContainer").style.overflowX = "auto";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery `prop()` function:

```
$('#example').prop('cssStyle', 'cssValue');
```

For you:

```
$('#example').prop('pagingType', 'full_numbers');
```

Comment: Didn't work. Maybe i must include somehow the "dataTable" or use the opener. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: if `$('#example')` is a datatable AND is created will work, if not, you must create first datatable and then change css value with `prop`